# Unique index error on INSERT with SELECT and NOT EXISTS check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, insert, indexing

I'm getting following error if i'm running a stored-procedure

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object ‘dbo.tabTac’ with unique index
>   ‘IX_tabTac’.

Unique Index `IX_tabTac`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tabTac] ON [dbo].[tabTAC] 
(
    [TAC] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Table `tabTac`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabTAC](
    [idTAC] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TAC] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [fiModel] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tabTac] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idTAC] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tabTAC]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tabTac_modModel] FOREIGN KEY([fiModel])
REFERENCES [dbo].[modModel] ([idModel])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tabTAC] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tabTac_modModel]
```

Stored-Procedure `InsertTacsFromClaims`:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[InsertTacsFromClaims]
with execute as Owner
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tabTac
        select substring(t.SSN_Number,1,8)as TAC
        ,m.idModel as fiModel
        from tabData t 
        inner join modmodel m 
            ON t.fimodel=m.idmodel 
        WHERE  t.fiproducttype=1
        and m.idModel>1
        and not exists(
            select fiModel from tabTac WHERE TAC=substring(t.SSN_Number,1,8)
        )
        GROUP BY substring(t.SSN_Number,1,8),m.idModel
END 

RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;
```

I would have thought that i have prevented this error with:

```
and not exists(
            select fiModel from tabTac WHERE TAC=substring(t.SSN_Number,1,8)
          )
```

**Edit**:

@Sparkys second query(ModelName added) returns following:

```
TAC         fiModel    ModelName
01233300    777        U5A
01238300    771        W20I
01238300    784        W20
35427603    720        C903
35773704    781        E15I
35905104    451        W595
35946804    793        W150I
35959004    813        ST18I
```

Now it's obvious that one TAC in tabData(first 8 chars of SSN_Number)has not a distinct model but can be linked to multiple models. That causes the error because in tabTac the TAC must be unique.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if the SSN_Number is duplicated in the TabData table or if the join to modModel produces duplicates.

```
select substring(t.SSN_Number,8),count(*)
from tabData
groub by substring(t.SSN_Number,8)
having count(*) > 1
```

and

```
  select substring(t.SSN_Number,1,8)as TAC
        ,m.idModel as fiModel
        from tabData t 
        inner join modmodel m 
            ON t.fimodel=m.idmodel 
        WHERE  t.fiproducttype=1
        and m.idModel>1
        GROUP BY substring(t.SSN_Number,1,8),m.idModel
        HAVING count(*) > 1
```

If either query returns duplicate SSN_numbers, you'll get the error.   Your code only checks that you don't add a SSN number from the table if it already exists in the table you are trying to populate, but doesn't account for potential dupes in the data already

There are several approaches to only get the most recent fiModel code, here is one example:

```
select SSN_Number,fiModel 
FROM tabData td1
JOIN
(  -- This will get the latest date from tabData
select SSN_Number,max(received_date) as TheLastestDate
FROM tabData td
LEFT JOIN tabTac tc on tc.TAC = substring(TD.SSN_number,1,8) 
                       and tc.fiModel = td.fModel
WHERE tc.fiModel is NULL
GROUP BY SSN_Number) xx ON xx.SSN_number=td1.ssn_number 
                           and td1.received_date = xx.TheLatestDate
```

Note that if you have multiple fiModels on the same date, the above won't handle it because it does not know how to distinguish between which to use.   Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: `SSN_Number` is not unique in tabData(TAC[first 8 chars] is even more repeating)  and the join to `modModel` cannot produce duplicates(tabData contains multiple claims with the same model, but every model is unique in modModel). But my `NOT EXISTS` check should avoid that i insert a TAC twice, at least I thought so.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out from your second query that tabData can contain the same TAC for different models what is forbidden in tabTac.

Comment: Done the same thing myself more than once or twice :)

Comment: But i still don't understand your point: "Your code only checks that you don't add a SSN number from the table if it already exists in the table you are trying to populate". All i want is to ensure that no TAC is inserted more than once, this is ensured with the unique index. But why does the `not exists` not prevent from this error.

Comment: The NOT EXISTS get evaluated as part of building the inner query and prevents any existing models fiModel, SSN's in the tabTac table from being reinserted.  The code adds the first occurrence from the query fine, but when the second occurrence occurs, the NOT EXIST is not reevaluated, hence it attempts the INSERT that causes the error...

Comment: Thanks for clarification. How can i change the stored-procedure to prevent it from inserting multiple TAC's? If there are multiple models assigned to a TAC in tabData, i would like to select only the newest(order by Received_Date desc).

Comment: I am heading into my office, but essentially you need to create a subquery which returns the SSN, Model for the most recent date.  I know that question comes up quite a bit on Stack Overflow, I'll see if I can find a link to an example once I get in my office...

Comment: I don't want to distract you from your work. But i would be glad to see an example(assuming that i need a [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) somewhere). Optimally it would select the record that appears the most often and if there are still multiple the newest(Received_Date desc).

Comment: I added an additional query to the answer which should get you started in the right direction of building the inner query